# Why Does Rails Server Take Forever to Start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.2 app on Ruby 2.0. It can take a couple **minutes** for `rails server` or `rails console` to get running. I guess my Macbook's hard drive isn't so great, but what can I do to the app to speed it up?

Here's how long rails console took on the first try:

```
real    2m57.496s
user    0m7.159s
sys 0m2.330s
```

It's faster afterwards, but still very slow:

```
real    0m51.230s
user    0m6.150s
sys 0m1.733s
```